# Parallel versions in PostgreSQL, What do I actually use?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

Os - ubuntu 18.04 (bionic)

I have installed postgresql 10 some time ago, and today i install a new version, 12.
I don't mind to throw all the previous data, so i tried to do `pg_ctl stop` for the old server. I am not able to execute the `pg_ctl stop` for the old server, because the command not found.
I found where postgres is installed, under `/var/lib/postgres` and it has two folders, one is `10` and the other is `12`. I tried to call pg_ctl from `10/main` but it does not appear also there. there is no `bin` folder there as well.
When I type `psql` under the postgres user, i get this info:
`psql (12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-2.pgdg18.04+1), server 10.12 (Ubuntu 10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1))`

I have search for hours in the docs and on the web, but i didn't find info for that.
Can you help me understand what is going on in my machine?

Edit: `pg_lsclusters` output:

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
10  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
12  main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
```

also, i can no longer connect to the new port. I have try to connect to port 5433 with postgres user and my password ( I have changed the pg_hba.conf row to authenticate with md5), but it didn't work.

Comment: Please post output of `pg_lsclusters`

Comment: On Ubuntu try to use `pg_ctlcluster` instead of `pg_ctl`. 
To stop PG 10 try: `pg_ctlcluster 10 main stop`
To stop PG 12 try: `pg_ctlcluster 12 main stop`

Comment: `psql (12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-2.pgdg18.04+1), server 10.12 (Ubuntu 10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1))` means you are using executable psql version 12.2 (client side) connected to PG cluster version 10.12 (server side).

Comment: @pifor so how can i change it to postgresql 12 server? just shut down the old server?

Comment: You don't need to shutdown the old server: you only need to give enough connection parameters to allow to connect the PG 12 server; try: `psql --port 5433`

Comment: It asks for password, and i after this it outputs ```password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/413585/postgres-password-authentication-fails.